# Guard not detecting file changes until I interact with terminal

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, readline, guard

I'm trying to get Guard to detect file system changes while I'm working with SASS files. I want them to be compiled to CSS. I *don't* want to interact with the terminal every time I make a change though. It should just happen automatically. Right now, I have to press enter at the terminal to get it to compile.

When I do `gem query --loacl` I get this:

```
coderay (1.0.9)
ffi (1.8.1)
formatador (0.2.4)
guard (1.8.0)
guard-sass (1.1.0)
listen (1.0.3)
lumberjack (1.0.3)
method_source (0.8.1)
pry (0.9.12.1)
rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
rb-inotify (0.9.0)
rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
sass (3.2.9, 3.2.8)
slop (3.4.4)
thor (0.18.1)
```

I should note that this will eventually be a `guard init` on a Samba share; the directory is not on my physical machine, but I am testing on my local hard drive.

To initialize the guard project, I did `guard init` and then `guard` on my 'Portfolio' directory. This my directory structure:

```
-- Portfolio
    -- sass
    -- css
    -- Guardfile (file)
```

And this is the contents of my guard file:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'sass', :input => 'sass', :output => 'css'
```

I read something about Ruby being compiled against libedit instead of readline. How can I check if this is the issue?

Comment: I had the same problem with ROR 5.1.5. The solution that I found is explained at:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227350/586195

Answer (score 3):

It appears the issue was in fact that Ruby wasn't using readline. I am not a Ruby expert, so I don't know for sure if this was the issue or not. I did [follow the directions here](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X) and installed the Ruby Version Manager (RVM) and reinstalled Ruby to version 1.9.3 (although I think I could have used the latest 2.0.0) and I reinstalled the guard and guard-sass gems and now my filesystem changes are being detected automatically.